# Google Analytics Event tracking inside a Mozilla PDF.js pdf

Tags: jquery, pdf, google-analytics

I have a site with an iFramed pdf using the [Mozilla PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), as so:

```
<iframe class="maxit" src="web/viewer.html?file=MaxIT.pdf#zoom=page-fit" frameborder="0">
<embed class="maxit" src="web/viewer.html?file=MaxIT.pdf" type="">
</iframe>
```

And i am using the analytics.js from google to track the page, as so:

```
<script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function() {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Everything works as intended, even standard event tracking on the page.
My problem is that i can't get it to track events when clicking links inside the pdf. For example, i have a couple og mailto links in the pdf, that i want to track. I am using the following script to send the event to GA, but nothing happens, even when i put the script and analytics.js directly on the web/viewer.html page. This is the script i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(this).attr("target");
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).click(function(event) { // when someone clicks these links
            event.preventDefault(); // don't open the link yet
            if (href.indexOf("mailto") !== -1) {
                ga('send', 'event', {
                    'eventCategory': "mailto link",
                    'eventAction': "clicked",
                    'eventLabel': href,
                    'transport': 'beacon'
                }); // create a custom event
                console.log("mailto clicked");
            }
            setTimeout(function() { // now wait 300 milliseconds...
                window.parent.open(href, (!target ? "_self" : target)); // ...and open the link as usual
            }, 300);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above script works fine, just not for links in the pdf.

Comment: Notice that PDF.js creates links dynamically, so you need to run your script every time a page is rendered and annotation layer is created. Or don't use jQuery and listen click events via single document.addEventListener('click', handler, true);

Comment: Of course, this worked. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

PDF are read by plugin browser and javascript can't parse their source code.
The only way you can add statitics on links is to use Analytics campaigns.

At the PDF creation, you have to decorate your Url links with the three parameters :

- `utm_source`
- `utm_medium`
- `utm_campaign`

For example : `https://www.example.com/?utm_source=courrier-d-ete-&utm_medium=e-mail&utm_campaign=soldes-d-ete`

Documentation : [Google Campaigns](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, all my links in the pdf are external links going to either a mailto or som other site, that i don't have tracking of. So the UTM way won't work.

Comment: That's why is a bad pratice to embed pdf file in web page ;)
With others tools, you could track the mouse drawing and the coords in the page where user clicked. But it's a bit heavy

Comment: Like heatmaps too